# android notification inboxStyle addLine

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using `InboxStyle` notifications so that I can append text with `addLine(txt)`.  Problem is that the same text is added for all notifications, even with different notification IDs! How can I hold a new `builder` object for each ID, that way `inboxStyle.addLine(txtMsg)` won't add a new line to all other notifications?

```
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

    inboxStyle.addLine(txtMsg);

    notificationManager.notify(userID, builder.build());
```

Comment: I dont quite understand, what is the requirement. Can you add an example to show what is desired?

Comment: Is your issue that the same text gets added multiple times? Or that you want separate notifications for each line rather than one notification which contains every line? If you could add some more code to clarify how you're trying to accomplish this currently, that would be useful.

Comment: a long time has past and not on that project now...  thinking I had multiple InboxStyle notifications, and adding a line thru addLine() to one of them would add a line to all of the currently displayed notifications (even though diff IDs).